# How to avoid flickers in Windows XP Virtual PC mode in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am using a Virtual PC. Ie, using Windows xp in virtual mode inside Windows 7. The graphics looks good but I am getting a lot of flickers (the Windows XP mode is by itself slow not my Windows 7 Operating system).

I saw many other posts in the forum, but none has anything related to this. Should I install a graphics driver?